# How do I use __repr__ with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Python 3.5.2)

I have defined `__repr__` for one of my classes as follows:

```
class d():
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = []
        return
    def __pos__(self):
        return self._values[0]
    def __repr__(self, value):
        self._values.append(value)
        return
```

Now I want

```
x = d()
print(x,"a")
print(+x)
```

to return

`a`

but instead I get

`TypeError: __repr__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

I've tried a few variations such as `print(x),"a"` with no luck.

Comment: ... `__repr__()` doesn't take *any* arguments...

Comment: And your function should  return a string, not nothing. The init also needs no return statement

Comment: (although technically it is legal to return nothing, or at least `None`, from `__init__()`)

Comment: `__repr__` is how you define what `repr(x)` does. It doesn't take any non-`self` arguments, it doesn't see that `"a"`, and it most definitely should not be adding things to lists.

Comment: Hm, so if I understand correctly, `__repr__()` 'works' with an optional argument, e.g. `def __repr__(self, value="b"):`, I just can't pass it an argument? 

Also, you're right cricket_007, thank you.

Comment: First things first, what is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I think that the real question is "Why do you want `__repr__` to take arguments"?  `__repr__` is supposed  to take an object (`self`) and return a string representation of that object.  It _shouldn't_ be mutating the object in any way and the object should have all the information that it needs to represent itself... so why do you need to have another argument passed?

Comment: @JackOffToJanetYellen: This question is like asking how to drive nails with a banana. That is not what bananas are for, and this is not what `__repr__` is for. What do you think `__repr__` is for?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of `__repr__()`?

Comment: I'm just trying to get a hang of writing my own classes and the magic methods of python. I wanted to see how far I can push things, and if I could make some fun unreadable code.

Comment: It helps to know something about the subject if you want to clever...

Comment: Wanting to make unreadable code shouldn't be fun, at least not when it gives trivial errors

Comment: Sorry, marinteau, I was reading out of [this list of magic methods](https://web.archive.org/web/20160317120552/http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.pdf) for python 2.7, I thought the different versioning might be why I encountered this error but I guess I was just trying to do something I cannot.

Comment: Trivial for you maybe! Thank you all though. Not sure how to close this thread.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to control how an instance of your class is displayed, the right way to do that is to override the `__format__` method. In general, the three methods you can override are used to:

1. `__repr__` - used when the object needs to be displayed  in the interactive interpreter, usually as a debugging aid. As far as possible, it should be a string that could recreate the object if evaluated.
2. `__str__` - used when the object is passed to `str` or called when `print` attempts to display your object. Without another definition, it simply calls `__repr__`. This is the "default" string representation for an instance.
3. `__format__` - used when your object is an argument to `str.format`. It receives as an additional argument the format specification (if any) that appears after the optional `:` in a replacement field.

Here is a simple example of a class to represent pairs of numbers. The character used to separate the numbers can be configured via the format specification.

```
class Pair():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __format__(self, spec):
        return "{}{}{}".format(self.x, spec, self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:/}".format(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pair({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

It can be used as follows:

```
>>> x = Pair(1,2)
>>> x  # using __repr__
Pair(1, 2)
>>> str(x)   # using __str__, with a default separator of /
'1/2'
>>> print(x)  # uses __str__ implicitly
1/2
>>> "{}".format(x)  # no separator specified
'12'
>>> "{:-}".format(x)  # use - to separate the two numbers
'1-2'
```

Note that in the case of `format`, the spec is not necessarily part *of* the return value, but acts as an instruction on *how* to format the value.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few people saying you should never add arguments to `__str__` or `__repr__` but I disagree.

For example, if you want to display the string representation of a class's objects you would write a custom `__str__`. But what if some of the objects were really long? Sometimes you may want to truncate those objects, sometimes you may want them in full.

```
class Compute:

    def __init__(self, foo, ...):
        self.foo = foo
        ...

    def __str__(self, trunc=False):
        return_str = ''
        for item in self.__dict__:
            if trunc:
                # If the length of the str representation of the item is long, shorten it.
                return_str += f'\n{item} = {self.__dict__[item] if len(str(self.__dict__[item] < 50) else str(self.__dict__[item])[:51]}'
            else:
                # This would be whatever your usual __str__ method returns
                return_str += f'\n{item} = {self.__dict__[item]}'

        return return_str
```

You would call this simply using:

```
bar = Compute(foo=...)

print(bar.__str__(trunc=True))
```

Now, if your `__init__` contains any objects whose length as a string is particularly long, (say you've got a large list of data) it will only print up to the 51st character.

You can add a lot more logic to how you want the truncated strings to be printed too.

I would recommend having default arguments set to False in the dunder method. This means that unless explicitly asked for, the `__str__` method can behave normally.

I have used this when I wanted to print a class's objects both to the terminal and to a log file. I only wanted them printed in full to the log file, and a truncated version to the terminal so I wrote something similar to this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really love your answer, thanks. I used a slight modification of that: I created a private method (I need this logic for indentation of my nested objects) _repr_nested(self, base_indent, indent, elem_sep); then real \_\_repr\_\_ just calls this internal method. I don't know about any downsides of your approach, but if they exist, this solves them.

Answer (score 2):

Your using `__repr__` the wrong way. `__repr__` should be used to return a representation of your object in a printable, formatted way. As opposed to Python simply printing the name and memory address of your object. Per the documentation of `__repr__`:

> Called by the `repr()` built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

I'm really not sure what your trying to achive with using `__repr__` though. If you simply want add an element to `self.values` via a method of `d`, ditch the magic methods and just create your own:

```
class d():
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = []

    def __pos__(self):
        return self._values[0]

    def append(self, value): # create your won function
        self._values.append(value)
```